# Sharp and Crisp Detail Lines In Sculpt Mode

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm in the 3d printing space and I wanted to sculpt detail lines on the surface of an object via sculpting. Whenever I do it, i get the rounded effect rather than the sharp hard crisp lines like on a gundam or a scifi model.

[image]

I've addded a picture of this item from Tron as an example.

So how would I go about adding those fine slightly indented detail lines  via sculpt?

Comment: I think you have to change the falloff in the brush settings to something different, say for example, the sharp falloff. You can change it on the top menu, right to the side of the radius and strength settings

Comment: i tried that, it's still giving me pixelated effects at the falloff.

Comment: Have you tried *hard surface modeling* techniques? Sculpting is good for organic models less good for hard surfaces.